# Manipulating data from long to wide

Tags: r

So I have a long dataframe in R as below

| Date | Name | Name 2 | Variable | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2018-06-30 | Germany | Italy | Benchmark | 30 |
| 2018-06-30 | Germany | Italy | Active | 50 |
| 2018-06-30 | Germany | Italy | Port | 20 |
| 2018-07-30 | Germany | Italy | Active | 50 |
| 2018-07-30 | Germany | Italy | Port | 20 |
| 2018-07-30 | Germany | Italy | Benchmark | 30 |

But I want to change it to something like this:

| Date | Name | Name 2 | Port | Bench | Active |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2018-06-30 | Germany | Italy | 20 | 30 | 50 |
| 2018-07-30 | Germany | Italy | 20 | 30 | 50 |

How should I do that? Reshaping it against Name & Date does not solve my problem...

Comment: Reshape using `Date/Name/Name2` as id variables and `Variable` as your time/grouping variable.

Comment: This was already asked and answered before. I am voting to close this down